# Scoping when nesting objects/functions

Tags: javascript, scoping

I'm relatively new to JS and I'm trying to follow how scoping works with child objects/functions.

For example:

```
const b = {
  c: () => {
    console.log("C", foo)
  }
}
const x = (foo) => {
  console.log("X", foo)
  return {
    a: () => {
      console.log("A", foo)
    },
    b: b 
  }
}

i = x("FOO")
i.a()
b.c()
```

I'm hoping to see the output `FOO` in all 3 cases - however I actually see:

> X FOO
>
> A FOO
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined at Object.c

I'm trying to create a function where all it's methods are actually mapped to external/imported methods, but since these all need access to `foo` this isn't working. Is there a way in which `b` (`c`) can gain access to the `foo`?  Or an alternative way of handling this situation?

Comment: Put the code for `b` and its `c` method *inside* the `x` function, so that it has `foo` in scope, then call `i.b.c()`.

Comment: `foo` is defined as a parameter to `x`. It does not exist anywhere outside of `x`. There are probably a number of ways in which you can pass that value around somehow, but it's unclear what approach exactly fits your situation.

Comment: @Bergi as I explained `b` is external code that is being imported, so I can only reference it in `x` rather than actually include it.

Comment: @match In that case, if the external code does reference an undeclared variable, you can't do much. Other than defining a global `foo` value. You really should fix the external code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `b` within the `x` function so that it can access the parameter value `foo` - it's not in scope otherwise. If you have to import `b` from somewhere else, you will need to change the other module to export a function so that you can provide `foo` for creating the `b`:

```
function makeB(foo) {
  // `foo` is in scope here
  return {
    c() {
      console.log("C", foo)
    }
  };
}

function x(foo) {
  // `foo` is in scope here
  console.log("X", foo)
  return {
    a() {
      console.log("A", foo)
    },
    b: makeB(foo), 
  };
}

const i = x("FOO");
i.a();
i.b.c();
```

Comment: Thanks for this - having read up some more on scoping I think this is going to be the easiest way to achieve what I want - to keep `x` as close as possible to a mapping, and hold the (lengthy) functions elsewhere.

Comment: @match Depending on how you want to use those functions, you might also consider making them methods, storing `foo` as a property of the object, and access it through `this` in the methods.

Answer (score 0):

move the definition of b inside the return object of function x

```
const x = (foo) => {
console.log("X", foo)
return {
  a: () => {
    console.log("A", foo)
  },
  b: {
    c: () => {
      console.log("C", foo)
    }
  }
}
```

}

now you will have access to foo thanks to closure.

Comment: In my 'real-world' code `b` is being imported from an external module, so I can only reference it rather thanh actually include it in `x`.

Comment: You can create a getter and setter in the return object of function x, then pass them to to function c. Thats if you can pass c a paramters.